# What does ‘Disinterestedness’ mean in the context of Mertonian norms?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, sociology

With ref to the CUDOS Mertonian norms...I used to think disinterestedness mean’t striving to be objective but I now think the intended meaning was for it to be taken literally.

Comment: See [Mertonian norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertonian_norms#Disinterestedness) : "*disinterestedness* : scientific institutions act for the benefit of a common scientific enterprise, rather than for the personal gain of individuals within them."

Comment: If the definition of *special interest* is: (noun) a group of people or an organization seeking or receiving special advantages, typically through political lobbying -- the 'disinterestedness' means avoiding such political or personal biases.

Answer (score 1):

See [Mertonian norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertonian_norms#Disinterestedness) :

> *disinterestedness* : scientific institutions act for the benefit of a common scientific enterprise, rather than for the personal gain of individuals within them.

[Robert K. Merton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_K._Merton) was a sociologist and not an epistemologist.

Thus, her norms are addressed to scientific institutions: a sort of ethics of the scientific enterprise.